# How to use a url as the InputSource for StringReader

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I apologize for the stupid question, but I am trying to use a xml file that is online in the following code.

```
String uri =
 "http://www.myserver.com/xml?month=Jan";

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection =
            (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        InputStream xml1 = connection.getInputStream();

InputSource xml = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml1));
```

I have tried researching the answer before having to ask, but however I try to get this to work I get the error that "The constructor StringReader(InputStream) is undefined"

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
InputSource xml = new InputSource(xml1);
```

As the error message says, there is no constructor for [`StringReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) that takes an instance of InputStream.